# how to disable pseudo elements in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've a website visible [here](http://atgtravels.com/) and it has issues in the social link
at the header section & in the service section of home page. The social links are displayed beneath the the top navigation bar due to this pseudo element:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: initial;
}
```

If I remove this code in the inspect element the design issues are gone. My first question is : 
1. how to track down the Pseudo elements in wordpress?
2. how to disable them to resolve my issue?

Comment: Sorry! I myself find the answer. I just change the code:                              *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}                                                                                                                       & put it in the Additional CSS Element in Customize Section & got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I myself find the answer. I just change the code:

```
*, *:before, *:after { 
    box-sizing: inherit; 
}
```

And put it in the Additional CSS Element in Customize Section & got the expected result.